# Java: Trying to repaint paintComponent() in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, paint, java-8

I have the following class extending `JPanel` (which currently doesn't make much sense from where it's being called to repaint, so ignore that. I'll be happy with it it painting anything for the meantime):

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawCounter(g);
    }

    private void drawCounter(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(100,80,70,40);
        g.drawString("Dia Dhuit", 105, 100);
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant code in the main class:

```
public class AUIApplet3 extends JApplet {
    GamePanel gamePan;

    public void scheduleNumbers(int[] randomNumbers, int speed, int amount) {
        long initialDelay = INITIAL_DELAY;
        final AtomicInteger curNumber = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        System.out.println(getNumbersAsString());

        final Runnable setNumber = () -> {
            currentNumberLab.setText(Integer.toString(randomNumbers[curNumber.incrementAndGet()]));
            System.out.println(randomNumbers[curNumber.get()]);
            gamePan.repaint();
        };

        setNumberService = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(setNumber, initialDelay, speed, MILLISECONDS);

        endNumberService = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            currentNumberLab.setText("");
            answerField.setEditable(true);
            checkAnswerBut.setEnabled(true);
            gameStatus = GameStatusEnum.WAITING;
            System.out.println("Finished in scheduleNumbers() lambda");
            setNumberService.cancel(true);
        }, ((speed * amount)+ initialDelay), MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Here's the entire code for the [AUIApplet3](http://pastebin.com/y2CPkyAZ) and [GamePanel](http://pastebin.com/S1S9CLh0) classes.

Where I'm calling `repaint()` in the `Runnable` lambda inside `scheduleNumbers()`, I'd like to paint something each time to the `gamePan` `JPanel`. And then eventually expand on `GamePanel`'s `paintComponent()` so that what's being painted is updated with different values each time as well as being able to paint images whenever a game is won or lost by the user.

As of right now, the code doesn't paint anything. I'm not entirely sure I'm implementing `GamePanel` correctly.

**Edit (Updated code):**

Is now printing but is displaying on the wrong panel despite `repaint()` being called on `feedbackPan`.

[image]

```
public void scheduleNumbers(int[] randomNumbers, int speed, int amount) {
    long initialDelay = INITIAL_DELAY;
    final AtomicInteger curNumber = new AtomicInteger(-1);
    System.out.println(getNumbersAsString());
    final Runnable setNumber = () -> {
        currentNumberLab.setText(Integer.toString(randomNumbers[curNumber.incrementAndGet()]));
        System.out.println(randomNumbers[curNumber.get()]);
        feedbackPan.repaint();
    };
    setNumberService = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(setNumber, initialDelay, speed, MILLISECONDS);
    endNumberService = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        currentNumberLab.setText("");
        answerField.setEditable(true);
        checkAnswerBut.setEnabled(true);
        gameStatus = GameStatusEnum.WAITING;
        System.out.println("Finished in scheduleNumbers() lambda");
        setNumberService.cancel(true);
    }, ((speed * amount)+ initialDelay), MILLISECONDS);
}

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawCounter(g);
    }

    private void drawCounter(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("test");
        g.drawRect(10,10,50,70);
        g.fillRect(10,10,50,70);
        g.drawString("Dia Dhuit", 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not reprinting? GamePanel doesnt do a lot...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't even think of checking that. It's being called. Any idea why it isn't being painted when the code is being called? Is it to do with gamePan having multiple other JPanels inside it?

Comment: You also seem to be violating the single thread rules of Swing. Swing is not thread safe and you shouldn't update any part of the ui outside of the event dispatching thread

Comment: yeah, hat won't help, as paintComponent pants the background of the component

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is that when I use the `newScheduledThreadPool`? Is there a way to make it compliant? Or rather, are there any alternatives that wouldn't require much changing of my code? I must have it handed up tonight.

Comment: You could use a Swing Timer or SwingUtilities.invokeLater. Generally speaking, I'd avoid Schedular and prefer to use a Swing Timer or simply a Thread with Thread.sleep (so long as you scychronise the updates with the EDT)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Damn, I'll keep that in mind for next time or try to fix it up if I have the time before I hand it up. Is it a major issue or should my code be grand for the most part?

Comment: No, it's a major issue ;)